# Seeding Entity Framework Code First

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am reading this about seeding a database, and I wonder, if I create a seed with 10 items, every time I migrate or update the database, will it be reseeded, so that I now have 20 items in my database?

I want to seed X items, that are constant in my database, how do I do it?

THanks.

[Seeding Tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your seed method you should use the `AddOrUpdate` method.

Imagine you are populating a table of Countries. You would have code in your seed method like this:

```
context.Countries.AddOrUpdate(
    c => c.Code,
    new Country { Code = "CA", Description = "Canada" },
    new Country { Code = "US", Description = "United States" });
```

Each time this code runs EF will query the DB to see if a country exists with a matching `Code` column. If not, it will do an INSERT, otherwise it will attempt to update the Country with the current values in the seed method.

Let's say you've already run `update-database` and the above data has been created. Then you change "United States" to "United States of America". Like this:

```
context.Countries.AddOrUpdate(
    c => c.Code,
    new Country { Code = "CA", Description = "Canada" },
    new Country { Code = "US", Description = "United States of America" });
```

The next time you run `update-database` EF won't create a new Country row. It will just update the existing row with `Code == "US"`.

One further thing to note is to **not** use `c => c.Id` as your `identifierExpression` (the first argument). Reason being is Ids typically use the IDENTITY specification, meaning its value gets generated by the database. Therefore it is not a reliable way of determining a matching row. I've seen this done a number of times, and the result is always duplicated records in the database.

So for clarity, **DON'T DO THIS:**

```
context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(
    x => x.Id,
    new Foo { Id = 1, Value = "Don't do this" });
```

The Id you put in the object initializer won't be used when the row is created. A generated value will be used instead. However, the Id you specified *will* be used when EF is trying to find a match later (for updates). It is extremely unlikely the IDs will match, and EF will rightfully think it has to create a new row, thus duplicating your data.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

In order to keep ten items you will need to check for their presence in your Seed method.

**Slightly longer answer**

Msdn [DbMigrationsConfiguration.Seed Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829453%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) states

> Note that the database may already contain seed data when this method runs. This means that implementations of this method must check whether or not seed data is present and/or up-to-date and then only make changes if necessary and in a non-destructive way.